# How to get latest post excerpt from a specific category?

Tags: wp-query

I'm working on a theme homepage and would like to include an excerpt from the latest post in a specific category.  In this case, the category slug is "gear".  I've tried a couple options with `WP_Query` but am unable to get it to return only one post.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php $latest1 = new WP_Query();
$args=array('category_name=gear','posts_per_page=1');
$latest1->query($args);
while ($latest1->have_posts()) : $latest1->the_post(); ?>
<h1 class="home-article-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<div class="storycontent">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

There are currently two posts in the "gear" category, and both are being returned.  I must be misunderstanding the posts_per_page option.

If there's a better way to do this than WP_Query (making this call three times on the page, once for each category), I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Did you check for the existence of a filter on 'pre_get_posts' which might override your args settings?

Comment: @marfarma I'm building this theme based on _s and haven't added any filters on pre_get_posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query("category_name=$catName&paged=$paged&posts_per_page=1");
```

Basically, add the paged variable to the args -- since it's your home page, you could hard code it to equal 1, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked the code such that 'posts_per_page' => 1,        'paged' => 1 and things are now working.